# Beautiful Soup Finding if a tag exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to figure this code out with using Beautiful Soup. What I want it to do since it I am pulling various pages and they don't have consistent tags, if it finds one tag to run that code and if it finds another tag to run another code, but I've had no success so far, I'd appreciate some help:

I am not getting any error messages, I do not know if the loop breaks or if it just skips it but it's not printing anything.

The URLs are:

1. http://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/Grand_Theft_Auto_V/
2. http://store.steampowered.com/app/578080/PLAYERUNKNOWNS_BATTLEGROUNDS/

The code I have is:

```
for price in pricing:

        if pricing.find('discount_final_price'):
            game_price = price.find('discount_final_price')
            gamprice = game_price[i].text
            print("Price:" + gamprice)  
        else :
            game_price = price.find("game_purchase_price price")
            gamprice = game_price[i].text
            print("Price:" + gamprice)
```

Comment: did you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: put url in question (not in comment) so we could check tags in HTML.

Comment: both pages ask for "date of birth" first. And probably they save it in some cookie. You may need this coockie when you try to get page with price. If you use `requests` then you can easily set this cookie. But first you have to find it - ie. in your browser.

Comment: @furas Ah I see, I'll see if I can find it so , Thank you

Comment: After setting date of birth in GTA I see cookie `birthtime: -2208989360`. If I remove it then it ask for date of birth again.

Comment: second link sets cookie `mature_content:1` with `path: /app/578080`

Comment: @furas I added the following "import requests
cookies = { 'birthtime': '-2208989360', 'mature_content': '1' }
r = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/', cookies=cookies)" now I am getting an error "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

Comment: it seems you get list with many elements instead of single element, so you have to use `for` loop to work with every element separately.

Comment: I see some mistake in code in question - you get single element using `for price in pricing:` but later you use all list in `if pricing.find(..)` - it should be `if price.find(..)`

Comment: @furas Right.. sorted that now just just getting     gamprice = game_price[i].text
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: use `print(game_price)` and you will see that you get `None`. **Correction:** `game_price` instead of `gamprice`

Comment: @furas So I've updates the code "   for price in pricing:

   if price.find('discount_final_price'):
    game_price = price.find('discount_final_price')
    #gamprice = game_price[i].text
    print("Price:" + game_price) 
   elif price.find("game_purchase_price price"):
    #gamprice = game_price[i].text
    print("Price:" + game_price)

   else:
    break " but now I'm getting no errors and it's not printing so feels like back to square 1

Comment: scrapping is not easy. First you can use `print()` and `print(type(...))` to check data in variables. Second you can check tags on pages again - maybe you are checking in wrong tags (or subtags).

Comment: Third you can check in documentation if you use `find()` correctly

Comment: see doc for [find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) - as first argument it expect tag name, not `attribute` nor `class` nor `id` (like `'discount_final_price'` or `game_purchase_price price`). If you want to search by attribute then you need ie. `find(attrs={"class": "game_purchase_price")`

Answer (score 9):

hi I dont know what is in the price variable but this code work well :

```
for price in pricing:

    game_price = soup.find('div', class_='discount_final_price')

    if game_price != None :
        print( "Price : {}".format(game_price.text) )

    else :
        game_price = pricing.find('div', class_='game_purchase_price price')
        print( "Price : {}".format(game_price.text) )
```